# Why other intent action is received when widget provider intent filter has only update action (Android)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-widget

My WidgetProvider - BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml has only one intent filter of action = "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"

```
<receiver android:name=".WidgetProvider">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

Then how can it receive other intent action such as "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED", "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED","android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED", ... ?
(I don't want to receive some of them)

Comment: That `<intent-filter>` simply indicates to the system that you have an App Widget available. Your `AppWidgetProvider` will be sent explicit broadcasts – i.e., `Intent`s that target that specific component – so the action on that `Intent` is not used to filter eligible components. You can't really prevent the system from sending you all of those different broadcasts. Just don't do anything in the corresponding methods for those that you don't want to respond to.

Comment: thanx... i do not do anything in the corresponding methods.. but, i just wonder about receiving an Intent which is not <intent-filtered> to the receiver